# mini.css modal dialog size

Tags: css, mini.css

On the docs page of mini.css https://minicss.org/docs#modal-dialogs , there's a modal dialog example. It works, and everything's fine, just the size (width to be precise) of the dialog seems to be constant, regardless of the screen size. It's very short, even on quite wide screens. Is there a way to make it wider (e.g. to take 70% of available space)?

Perhaps the problem is trivial, yet I'm not a CSS expert. I've checked the size of div elements, and they are set to 100%. Just the modal part is rendered so small.

Answer (score 0):

It is using a media query , Override that media query.

```
media screen and (min-width: 320px)
.card {
     max-width: 70%; //try !important tag if does not work without it.
}
```

Or probably define your own media queries.